# How to make newsfeed using relational tables in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a news feed right now but there are some errors that I am facing.

Now this is the structure of my `friends table` and my `post`

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+  +----------+---------+--------------+
|     id    | user_one  |  user_two |  |    id    | user_id |     post     |
|-----------+-----------+-----------+  |----------+---------+--------------+
|     1     |     12    |    43     |  |     1    |   12    |This is post 1|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|  |----------|---------|--------------|
|     2     |     43    |    36     |  |     2    |   36    |This is post 2|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+  |----------|---------|--------------|
                                       |     3    |   43    |This is post 3|
                                       +-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now here in this simple table my id is **43**
I am freind with **12** and **36**. Now in the newsfeed when I make the query of `mysql` it will show only the posts of the users who I am friend with, it's not showing my posts.

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION['my_id'];

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `friends`");
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
        $f = $row1['user_one'];
        $s = $row1['user_two'];
        if($f == $id){
            $user= $s;
        }elseif($s == $id){
            $user= $f;
        }else{
            $user= $id;
        }
        $query2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts`");
        while($row2= mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        $post= $row2['post'];

        $pic= u_info($user, 'profile_picture');
        $u_fn= u_info($user, 'first_name');
        $u_ln= u_info($user, 'last_name');

        if(!empty($post) == true){
?>
<div id='news'>
    <div id='activity'>
        <img src='pp/<?php echo "$pic";?>' id='pic'>
        <a href='profile?id=<?php echo "$user";?>' class='name'><?php echo "$u_fn $u_ln"?></a>
    </div>
    <?php echo "<p class='post'>$post</p>";?>
</div>
<?php } } }?>
```

Now the function `u_info` I created and it's working fine

How to make it properly working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time that you are doing a loop inside a loop, it can be simplified by a `JOIN` query.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`
WHERE user_id = $id // Select your posts
OR user_id IN ( // Select your friends/posts
   SELECT user_one as user_id FROM `friends` WHERE user_two = $id 
   UNION
   SELECT user_two as user_id FROM `friends` WHERE user_one = $id
   )
```

Now your code could be simplified to -

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION['my_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts`
        WHERE user_id = $id
        OR user_id IN (
           SELECT user_one as user_id FROM `friends` WHERE user_two = $id
           UNION
           SELECT user_two as user_id FROM `friends` WHERE user_one = $id
           )";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $post= $row['post'];
        $pic= u_info($row['user_id'], 'profile_picture');
        $u_fn= u_info($row['user_id'], 'first_name');
        $u_ln= u_info($row['user_id'], 'last_name');

        if(!empty($post) == true){
?>
<div id='news'>
    <div id='activity'>
        <img src='pp/<?php echo "$pic";?>' id='pic'>
        <a href='profile?id=<?php echo "$user";?>' class='name'><?php echo "$u_fn $u_ln"?></a>
    </div>
    <?php echo "<p class='post'>$post</p>";?>
</div>
<?php } }?>
```